# How to remove submodule changes from a git commit

Tags: git

My repository has a few submodules that were on an older version. When I updated my git repo all the submodule SHA also got refreshed. After making a change to my top-level git repo and doing `git commit -am"commit"` the submodule SHAs also got added to my commit. Not sure how to **unstage** those changes and keep my changes to the commit.

```
$ git show --name-only 

src/file1.cpp # My changes
src/file1.hpp # My changes
src/repo1 # Updated submodule SHA, how to get rid of this from my commit.
src/repo2 # Updated submodule SHA, how to get rid of this from my commit.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you oopsed an add, reset it. For

```
$ git show --name-only 

src/file1.cpp # My changes
src/file1.hpp # My changes
src/repo1 # Updated submodule SHA, how to get rid of this from my commit.
src/repo2 # Updated submodule SHA, how to get rid of this from my commit.
```

you'd

```
git reset @^ -- src/repo*
```

Comment: You mean `git reset HEAD~ -- src/repo*` ? as I've already created the commit.

Comment: Whoops, yes. I somehow misread show as diff. Fixed, thanks.